# 99% data redundancy in binary classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, dimensionality-reduction, smote

I am working on binary classification problem and there is 99.99% data redundancy. When I looked into the distribution of the classes both seem to be the same. Class imbalance is also part of the problem. Following is my analysis on the dataset:

1. **t-SNE Plots**

[image]

Generating t-SNE plots for different values (>4) produce same kind of graph where classes are on top of each other.

2. **PCA Analysis**

[image]

Top PCA components have very low variances spread across all of the features (total features=42).

Now I trained xgboost classifier with smote upsampling and top 5 PCA components (top 5 explains 80% of the variance). I did k fold cross validation with hyper parameter tuning. I analyzed decision boundaries for different of values of each xgboost hyper parameter. My F1 score is 0.11, which is not a good score.

Can anyone share thoughts on the current problem with all the information I provided? My main concern is if the underlying nature of the distribution might not be good from learning point of view. Because I know even if I deduplicate and train the model I might get good results but when tested on the real world data, I will have too many points from both classes which have exactly the same values (distribution).

Comment: In reality classes are often not well separated and overlap substantially. You cannot expect to get what you'd call a "good result" then. In such cases the data don't allow to predict the class with much precision whatever method you use. That's just how it is.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes that's the problem. Classes overlap too much to a point where classifier ends up learning too much from the seen data but never performs well on the unseen data.

Answer (score 0):

I dispute that the classes are so inseparable. For instance, in perplexity 4, observations around $(50, -20)$ are almost certainly going to be red, yet points around $(40, 30)$ seem to be an even mix of red and green. Since green is so outnumbered by red, a $50/50$ chance of green in a region is quite remarkable!

Now, t-SNE can create groupings that do not exist just as it can miss groupings that do exist, so that perplexity 4 plot is not necessarily indicative of how the real data look in many dimensions. Nonetheless, having clusters like this strikes me as at least a positive sign.

One of the issues perhaps leading you to have poor results is the concern with a threshold-based, improper scoring rule like $F_1$ score. Among the issues, $F_1$ score does not evaluate the XGBoost model. The $F_1$ score evaluates the XGBoost model along with a decision rule based on a threshold that might be wildly inappropriate for your task. A standard software default is a threshold of probability $0.5$. In all four of the plots, there are few regions where there will be a probability of $0.5$ of the point being green.

You might find yourself having better luck evaluating the raw outputs of your model instead of applying a software-default threshold. At the very least, you can tune the threshold to change your $F_1$ score.

Finally, it might be that the classes are simply quite similar and cannot be separated do a large extent on your data.

I will leave some links on class imbalance and the drawbacks of threshold-based performance metrics.

[Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)

[Profusion of threads on imbalanced data - can we merge/deem canonical any?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/profusion-of-threads-on-imbalanced-data-can-we-merge-deem-canonical-any)

[Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models)

[Academic reference on the drawbacks of accuracy, F1 score, sensitivity and/or specificity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603663/academic-reference-on-the-drawbacks-of-accuracy-f1-score-sensitivity-and-or-sp)